# How do I skip first rows with Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas

When I try to skip the first X rows when reading a CSV file using Pandas in Python instead of getting the rest of the CSV file i only get that specific row from where it should start.

I.e. skiprows=1, will ONLY output row 1.

Any idea why this is happening

- This question is different, because I can't get what I read in the other question to work, which is why I posted here saying that I don't get the expected result

Comment: it looks like you are also using `nrows=1` parameter... Can you show your `pd.read_csv()` call?

Comment: this is my read CSV line: df = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=cols,skiprows=Y,nrows=X)